# C check if last character of string is equal with X

Tags: c, string, arduino

im writing a sketch for my arduino and i would like to check the last character of my string.

#### For example:

If the input is `cats-` i want to see if the last char (in my case is "-") is actualy -

#### The code im using:

The serial event function

```
void serialEvent() {
 while (Serial.available()) {
  // get the new byte:
  char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
  // add it to the inputString:
  inputString += inChar;
  // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
  // so the main loop can do something about it:
  if (inChar == '.') {
    stringComplete = true;
  } 
 }
}
```

This is checking if the input string is completed by checking the input is equals with `-`. However this is working only with the console because the python script im using is sending everything together

```
void loop() {
 if (stringComplete) {
 Serial.println(inputString);
 display.clearDisplay();
 display.setTextSize(1);
 display.setCursor(0,0);
 display.println("Altitude:");
 display.println(inputString);
 display.display();
 // clear the string:
 inputString = "";
 stringComplete = false;
}
```

Any idea on how to check it?

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Comment: @immibis lol, for some reason it was tagged as "python" because i had the word python above.

Comment: `if (inputString[strlen(inputString) - 1] == '-')`?

Comment: @mch cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'

Comment: This (as noted elsewhere) looks suspiciously more like C++ than plain C. If so, please correct, as the answers given depend on the correct language tag.

Comment: I assume that your "== '.'" Is just a typo here and is actually "== '-'" in your code?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? it doesn' look like C to me.

Comment: What type is `inputString` then, for a construction as `inputString += inChar;` to work? In C, you cannot overload operators, so this suggests `inputString` is a numerical value, and adding 'characters' to it is not a sensible operation.

Comment: @Jongware The input can be anything. From letter to numbers. Im using this method simply because the serial protocal can send only 1 value at a time. So i have to keep adding them inside that char untill the delimiter is entered

Comment: Sorry, you seem to be missing the crucial point that *this is not valid C syntax*. It must be C++, whether you realize it or not.

Comment: @Jongware Unless you dont know how to use google or you dont have any idea what an arduino is the language is merely a set of C/C++ functions. However the syntax style is C

Comment: This line: ' inputString += inChar;', in C,  does NOT append a character to a string.  What is does in append a character to the address of inputString.  If you enabled all the compiler warnings, it would have told you there was a problem.  A useable method would be: inputString[strlen(inputString)+1] = '\0';  inputString[strlen(inputString)] = inChar;  the first statement would only be needed ft the code has skipped clearing the inputString[] buffer to all  '\0' before inserting characters

Comment: this line: 'Serial.println' is NOT C.

Comment: Most definitely not C. Also  `'.'` is not a newline character ;-)

Comment: Voting to close.  This is unclear what OP wants: OP insists code is "syntax style is C", but it is clearly not C, yet tagged C: `inputString += inChar;`, `void serialEvent()`,  Arduino language is a set of C/C++ functions and OP is using constructs from both languages, hence C++.

Comment: I suggest retagging as java

Comment: If the code and the comments disagree, then both are probably wrong. -- Norm Schryer

Comment: It could be more helpful for the OP to migrate this question to [Arduino.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the last character of a `std::string` is `s.back()` (UB if the string is empty, so check first.) I know that your question is tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c), but the code itself is using `std::string` so I suppose it is really C++.

The `back()` member function, which is analogous to the member function with the same name in sequenced containers like `std::vector`, was officially added in C++11, so it may or may not be present. If it isn't, you can use:

```
*(s.end()-1)
```

or:

```
s[s.size()-1]
```

If `s` were really a C string (i.e. a `char *`), you would have to use:

```
s[strlen(s)-1]
```

but `strlen` needs to read the entire string, so it is not as efficient.

All of the above suffer from the same problem as `s.back()`: if the string is empty, the result is Undefined Behaviour, so you need to check first.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (inChar == '.') {
    stringComplete = true;
}
```

to

```
if (inChar == '\n') {
    stringComplete = true;
}
```

The newline character is `'\n'` in `C`, `C++`, `java`, `javascript` and many more...  But whatever your language may be, you probably should not add the linefeed character to the string.